# Get compiling information from VS code language plugins

Tags: visual-studio-code, plugins

I'm working on a static code checking tool. Rather than analyzing so many different programming languages myself, I'm wondering if there is a way to get compiling information from VS code language plugins?

What I need looks like:

1. Positions of class, methods, parameters, etc (start and end line/column no. or index)
2. All the imports/includes/using... at the beginning of code files...
3. Methods calling...

Since the language plugins should tell the vs code how to highlight those things, so I think there might be some information I can use. Isn't it?

Any information will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-server-extension-guide